# Beginning Computer Programming

Tags: c

I was 7 years old when I learnt BASIC. Then I learnt C and Visual Basic till the age of 13. I stopped programming for 4 years continuously, and don't remember much about it now. I have lost the skill, and need to do learn it all over again.

> How can I learn basics and the terminology of programming all over
>   again using C?

Can someone suggest an E-Book for that?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general programming.  It should likely be asked on stackoverflow, or one of the other stack exchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

The process of learning or re-learning depends on the reason for which you want to do it. Since your on Scicomp, I assume that your needs are related to a scientific project (BE, Ms, PhD ...) that requires you to understand/write/use computational codes (based on finite volume, finite element ...) to implement a numerical model. Therefore my advice, *if this is the case* is that you do not need ebooks to get going in the beginning because they usually contain a lot of information, which sometimes make the learning process boring. You can start with the following:

**Tutorials**

I personally think tutorial sites like [CProgramming](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/c-tutorial.html) and [C_Programming](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/C_Programming) are great for their simplicity, the step-by-step approach with nice examples along the way. After that, you should copy the examples and do some "experiments" to grasp the basics (not the basics tought to a 13-year old :) ): changing variable types, defining functions, dealing with input and output ... 
On the side, it's always good to have reference guides. They tend to be heavy in details, but they're useful occasionally for some reminders or some technical detail.

**StackOverFlow**

For all your easy, moderate and difficult programming tasks, StackOverFlow can be very useful for both solving issues and learning, specially when you begin experimenting things and reach the limit of what you know

Comment: I'd like to add just one more resource to your answwer: Learn C the Hard Way. The author emphasizes the importance of actually writing code as you're learning, not just reading pages and pages of tutorials without actually trying any of it out.

http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/